# Padding of hr elements not showing up consistently

Tags: css

I have two `hr` elements and set each to have a different class (so I could set a special `margin-bottom` value for one of them). I'm wondering why the padding declaration is only taking effect for the first (with class "top"). Any ideas?

For full code view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/PRrJbb)

HTML:

```
  <hr class="top">
    <p>
    Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  <hr class="bottom">
```

CSS:

```
hr.top {
  border-top: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
  width: 4em;
  padding: 3em;
}

hr.bottom {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
  width: 4em;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I don’t have an answer but just want to say this is a very well organized and thoughtful question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding is working both for `.top` and `.bottom` classes. The reason You don't see expected result is the fact that border is rendered Outside, the padding area and it is not affecting the spacing You wanted to achieve. Here is the screen from "Computed" box model preview:
[image: css box model image]

Please use **Margins** instead of Padding to set proper spacing **Outside** the element.

In Your case it will be:

```
hr.top,
hr.bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
  width: 10em;
}

hr.top {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

hr.bottom {
  margin: 5em auto;
}
```

Ps. look into "Computed" tab while "inspecting" the element, and read some [Css Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Padding for both the `<hr>` tag is similar. You just need to switch between using border-top and border-bottom.

THIS:

```
hr.top {
  border-top: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
}
```

Should become:

```
hr.top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
}
```

Check the working snippet below

```css
hr.top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
  width: 4em;
  padding: 3em;
}

hr.bottom {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #9d9c9c;
  width: 4em;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<hr class="top">
    <p>
    Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  <hr class="bottom">
```